Changing an element's scrollLeft property in a functional component is ignored in React?
I am trying to scroll an element with mouse drag and I am facing a problem. When I try to change the value of an element's scrollLeft property it does not do anything and when I log the value it always stays at 0.
I even tried to give scrollLeft a value but it never changes from 0.
This is the code I am trying to use :


//App.js
import React from 'react';
import Slider from './slider.js';
import './style.css';

export function App(props) {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Slider>
        <div className="slide" id="1">Slide 1</div>
        <div className="slide" id="2">Slide 2</div>
        <div className="slide" id="3">Slide 3</div>
      </Slider>
    </div>
  );
}





//slider.js
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import './style.css';

const Slider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isDragging, setIsDragging] = useState(false);
  const [startX, setStartX] = useState(0);
  const [scrollLeft, setScrollLeft] = useState(0);
  const sliderRef = useRef();
  const startDrag = (e) => {
    setIsDragging(true);
    setStartX(e.pageX - sliderRef.current.offsetLeft);
    setScrollLeft(sliderRef.current.scrollLeft);
  };
  const endDrag = () => {
    setIsDragging(false);
  };
  const onDrag = (e) => {
    if (!isDragging) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - sliderRef.current.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX) * 2;
    sliderRef.current.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;//<-Does not do anything
    //sliderRef.current.scrollLeft+= 40;//<-Does not do anything too
    console.log(sliderRef.current.scrollLeft);//<-Allways outputs 0
  };
  return (
    <div
      className="slider"
      ref={sliderRef}
      onMouseDown={startDrag}
      onMouseLeave={endDrag}
      onMouseUp={endDrag}
      onMouseMove={onDrag}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Slider;





body {
  background: transparent; /* Make it white if you need */
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
}

.App {
  color: #72a24d;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.slide {
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: #333;
}

.slider {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: grab;
}

.slider:active {
  cursor: grabbing;
}



Is there something wrong with the way I set up the code?
I also noticed that if I tried to change the element's scrollLeft property via the inspector, the same thing happens : it always stays at 0 even if the code itself does not output any error.
